# Exclude a folder from disk quota (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, quota

I have a per-user disk quota on our server. Each user has their own folder to store data and whatnot. However, there is also a `public` folder which each user has access to. I was wondering if it was possible to exclude files in this folder from counting against a user's quota.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to exclude files from a disk quota, as the quota, by design, is managed at volume level.

One way to try to circumscribe this issue in your particular case is to :

1. create a separate volume
2. rename your current `public`folder and create a new empty one at the same location
3. mount this volume exposed not as a volume letter but exposed into your `public` folder
4. move back your `public` data into the new mounted volume
5. apply your quota to your principal volume, and of course *do not* apply quota on the `public` mounted volume